# How to bundle in GLFW3 with an Elixir Scenic app distribution for macOS

Tags: xcode, linker, elixir, release

I am building an Elixir app and I ended up using Scenic https://github.com/boydm/scenic to test some rendering components. When I bundle the app for release and try to run it on another macOS computer it first fails with Gatekeeper stuff (I understand it must be signed) and then once I manually approve all the services it still will not run due to missing GLFW3 library.

What would be the workflow to bundle the Elixir application with GLFW3 so if the application is downloaded via a Zip on a website the end-user wouldn’t have to install GLFW3 via terminal/homebrew? It would just run... I imagine it would somehow have to bundle together via Xcode? So a relatively manual process? Thanks.

Comment: _Bundle_ exactly how? _Run_ exactly how? _Error_ is exactly what? Please add some code. Also, _what is GLFW3_?

Comment: On mobile sorry - run just means running the binary that elixir spits out for a release. Scenic depends on GLFW3 which is a OpenGL library. https://hexdocs.pm/scenic/install_dependencies.html